# Enable Windows Authentication only for subdomain on IIS

Tags: iis, subdomain, windows-authentication

I have this situation where the main domain requires Anonymous Authentication while the sub-domain can only accept Windows Authentication for my app to work.

Currently, I can only do one or the other on IIS. Basically, in my service it's expecting `WindowsIdentity` and unless it's coming through `Windows Authentication` it'll becomes `ClaimsIdentity`. I want to ensure that the identity of this request is a Windows and is authenticated.

I've tried enable Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication for the main domain and disabled Anonymous Authentication & enabled Windows Authentication for sub-domain.

Folder and site structure:

**Folder**

inetpub
    /myservice
        /wwwroot
            /mysubdomain

**In IIS**

Default Web Site
    /myservice
        /wwwroot
            /mysubdomain

I made the request via `http://localhost/myservice/mysubdomain`. If I publish my service as `IIS` in Visual Studio 2019, Windows Authentication works but Anonymous Authentication doesn't. If I publish my service as `myservice` project then Anonymous Authentication works but Windows Authentication doesn't.

Comment: Are they separate applications, or all the same? If separate applications, are they under the same site in IIS (one is an app in a virtual folder of the other site) or are they separate sites?

Comment: I've update my question, if that helps. They're sitting in the same app.

Answer (score 0):

I have this sorted out. It's not the ideal solution I wanted but it worked around my problem. I had to change my app to accept only Windows Authentication.

Comment: And disable anonymous you mean? In the main site or the sub site? You shouldn't have to disable anonymous for the main site if you don't want to.

Comment: Apparently I had to. I've already tried everything I could imagined to enable anonymous for the main site and disable it for its sub-domain.

Comment: Was the "subdomain" site converted to an application in IIS? (in IIS Manager, right-click the folder under the site and click "Convert to Application)

Comment: Done that and what's not. I've pretty much done everything that make sense and don't.

Comment: Odd. It's hard to know what's wrong without seeing it, but it is certainly possible to use anonymous at the root and disable anonymous in an application under the root. I've done it.